# Using Twig to access HTML content

Tags: twig

I am working with Twig in Opencart 3.

If i have an HTML element

```
<span id='mobileCheck' style='display: none;'>mobile</span>
```

Is there any way to access either the id, or the content within Twig in order to use that in an if statement later?

In javascript i'd write

```
var isMobile = document.getElementById("mobileCheck").innerText;
```

Can i do something similar in Twig?

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to do inside the `if`. If you want to adjust/change content that has been processed before the `if`, then that is something u can't do.

Comment: I am hoping to use the value captured from the HTML as the decider for the IF to proceed with a mobile or desktop menu. 
The span is the very first object generated on the page.

Comment: Why don't you just use mediaqueries in CSS to display the correct menu instead of trying to do this in `twig`?

Comment: I need to change the menu twig/html structure for mobile, vanilla opencart just loads the entire desktop menu for mobile.

Comment: Read out both menus. Hide one or the other with mediaqueries. As simple as that, why would you overcomplicate this? Also doing this with `twig` makes your site almost uncacheable

Comment: Got hooked on the Mobile_Detect library and really really wanted to try implement it successfully

Comment: If I were you and you really wanted to use this library then add an instance as a global twig variable like `$twig->addGlobal('mobile_detect', new Mobile_Detect());` and now you can use that variable everywhere... `{% if mobile_detect.isMobile() %}{% include "nav/mobile.twig" %}{% else %}{% include "nav/desktop.twig" %}{% endif %}`